# Win32 API to do wildcard string match

Tags: c++, c, winapi, wildcard, glob

I am looking for a wildcard string match API (not regex match). I cannot use anything other than Win32 APIs.

Comment: What do youu mean by "wildcard string match"? Please give examples.

Comment: Examples or (preferably) a spec. If you mean identical rules to file wildcards on Windows, but don't explicitly say so, then typically Neil will press for a better requirements doc ;-) Also, it occurs to me that `*` and `?` in file globs don't match the backslash character - it might affect the answer whether or not you want this behaviour.

Answer (score 13):

There is [PathMatchSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773727(VS.85).aspx) - but handling is specialized for files, so results might not be what you expect if you need general wildcard matching.

Otherwise, you should probably go with an RegEx, as Pavel detailed.

**[edit]**
I *incorrectly* assumed `PathMatchSpec` shares the properties of [FindFirstFile/FindNextFile](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883). I've ran a few tests - it doesn't. So it looks like the best candidate.

Comment: A very interesting find. I wonder how is that thing specialized for paths, though (if it actually is).

Comment: Pavel, I checked - the special handling is only in FindFirst/NextFile. Yay! :D

Comment: What is the special handling? I don't see why it would not be the same? You mean it applies to the file name part only in FindFirst/NextFile?

Comment: @paulm: another thing is matching e.g. x.htm to *.html if 8.3 names is enabled. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/20/440918.aspx

Comment: _"Otherwise, you should probably go with an RegEx, as Pavel detailed"_. And after converting this to a RegEx, where is the Win32 API to manage it, as the OP requested?

Answer (score 9):

Strange that so many years passed and nobody gave you this answer:

There is a WIN32 API that does exactly what you're looking for. (I found it searching in the MSDN for "wildcard")

It's name is **[SymMatchString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681355(v=vs.85).aspx)**. It sits in `DbgHelp.dll` which is part of the operating system.

Put a CriticalSection around the API call if your app is mulithreaded!

The API that [**FindFirstFile**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) uses internally for wildcard matches is probably [**FsRtlIsNameInExpression**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-_fsrtl_advanced_fcb_header-fsrtlisnameinexpression).

Elmü

Comment: DbgHelp may be part of the operating system. Unfortunately, MS has this to say: "`Although this DLL is included in all supported versions of Windows, it is rarely the most current version of DbgHelp available. Furthermore, the version of DbgHelp that ships in Windows has reduced functionality from the other releases-- specifically, it lacks support for Symbol Server and Source Server.`" Personally, I wouldn't feel particularly comfortable deploying a solution using this API under such conditions.

Comment: How many applications are to run on SymbolServer or SourceServer? If you really worry about that you could install a known version of DbgHelp.dll into your program's folder and this will be loaded instead of the DLL of the OS.

Comment: `FsRtlIsNameInExpression` is a function for kernel mode drivers, exported by ntoskrnl.exe.  There is a user-mode function called `RtlIsNameInExpression` in Windows 7 and later, exported by ntdll.dll.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest thing would be to just convert your glob pattern to a regex, by the following rules:

- `*` becomes `.*`
- `?` becomes `.`
- Any of `\|.^$+()[]{}` are escaped by preceding them with `\`

This is partly true.
Following rules are inducted from DIR behaviour in XP+ Command Prompt:
`*` is the same as `*.*` and becomes regex `.+`
`?` becomes regex `.?` unless followed by a non-wildcard
`?` not followed by a wildcard becomes regex `.`
`*.` means "without extension", and becomes `[^.]+$`

Comment: Ok, but after converting the glob pattern to a regex, what's next? Where is the Win32 API to manage such regex? The OP wrote: _"I cannot use anything other than Win32 APIs"_...

Comment: There is a C++ tag on the question, so one would assume that the C++ standard library is not off-limits. It includes std::regex.

Comment: Ok, but in this case, the (standard) C tag is also included in the question. Could you suggest a standard C library to manage regex? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There isn't one, so the question doesn't have an answer if you restrict it to C. On Windows, you'll have to either use a third-party regex library, or use C++.

Answer (score 4):

The [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28VS.85%29.aspx) APIs do wildcard matches, but only against filenames.

You can't use *anything* but Win32?  What about STL or CRT?  Are you using Boost?

Without the Win32 API restriction, I would recommend using the code from some open-source project. Another option would be to translate the glob into a regex, which I believe can be done with a regex replace operation.

edit: First google match is the PHP code:

[http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/win32/](http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/win32/?diff_format=u)

Answer (score 3):

If you're after a simple wildcard compare ([globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)), some people have written their own, including [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/wildcmp.aspx) (which we use in our code)

Answer (score 0):

WHat exactly is your requirement? Are you just looking to use the '*' symbol to match 0 or more characters or are you planning on using the '?' symbol as well. If it is just '*', do you need to look for *a, a*, a*b, a*b*c, etc type patterns? If your requirement is limited, you could easily get away with the C++ runtime library's strstr function.